# UIViewPropertyAnimator state inside completion block?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

Playing around with UIViewPropertyAnimator, I am stuck in a weird problem.

Here,

```
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear)
    animator.addAnimations(someAnimationBlock)
    
    animator.addCompletion{ position in
                    
    switch position
    {
            case .current:
                        print("is current")
            case .start:
                        print("is start")
            case .end:
                        print("is end")
    
                        print(self.animator.state == .active)
                        print(self.animator.state == .inactive)
                        print(self.animator.state == .none)
                        print(self.animator.state == .stopped)
                        
    }
}

animator.startAnimation()
```

After this code runs, this comes to the completion block at `.end position` but all states are false for animator. Why is this happening ?

To my knowledge it should be at `.inactive` state as the animations got completed naturally.

P.s I was in the completion block trying to fire `animator.startAnimation()` and the completion block wasn't getting called anymore. I got to know that the `startAnimation()` works only when the `animator's` state is `.inactive`. So here I tested, and I am receiving no value for state, Need help!

Comment: What do you get if you `debugPrint(self.animator.state)` in the `.end`?

Comment: It will print '__C.UIViewAnimatingState'. If I debugPrint(self.animator.state.rawValue) it prints '5', according to apple documentation UIViewAnimatingState is an enum conforming to int and has three cases i.e. active, inactive and stopped, whose values are irrespectively 0,1 and 2. I don't understand why is this printing 5 which should not be the case.

Comment: @AmaisSheikh do you remember how did you resolve this issue? I encountered the same problem with the rawValue being `5`.

Answer (score 0):

When the animation's completion block is called and the position is `.end` the animation has completely finished and will soon be removed from the view.

Even if you were to call `startAnimation` again it's not going to have an effect because the animation is going to go away very soon anyway.

Instead of calling `startAnimation` from the completion block, you may be able to create new animations on the view and start those.

Comment: Scott my goal is that: setting the UIViewPropertyAnimator to isReversed = true -> adding a completion block to the animator object (for setting isReversed = false when animation completes)

Comment: Scott I am kind of unclear about UIViewPropertyAnimator for some behaviours, I would be highly thankful If you would clear me out on some concepts. I will be having maybe some more questions about UIViewPropertyAnimator. Can I have your twitter, so that I may notify you ?